# Jupyter + Apache toree - scala kernel is busy

Tags: apache-spark, jupyter-notebook, apache-toree

I've installed jupyter notebook over python 3.5.2 on ubuntu server 16.04
I also have installed apache toree to run spark jobs from jupyter.

I run:

```
pip3 install toree
jupyter toree install --spark_home=/home/arik/spark-2.0.1-bin-hadoop2.7/ # My Spar directory
```

The output was a success:

> [ToreeInstall] Installing Apache Toree version 0.1.0.dev8
>   [ToreeInstall] Apache Toree is an effort undergoing incubation at the
>   Apache Software Foundation (ASF), sponsored by the Apache Incubator
>   PMC.
>
> Incubation is required of all newly accepted projects until a further
>   review indicates that the infrastructure, communications, and decision
>   making process have stabilized in a manner consistent with other
>   successful ASF projects.
>
> While incubation status is not necessarily a reflection of the
>   completeness or stability of the code, it does indicate that the
>   project has yet to be fully endorsed by the ASF.
>
> Additionally, this release is not fully compliant with Apache release
>   policy and includes a runtime dependency that is licensed as LGPL v3
>   (plus a static linking exception). This package is currently under an
>   effort to re-license (https://github.com/zeromq/jeromq/issues/327).
>   [ToreeInstall] Creating kernel Scala [ToreeInstall] Removing existing
>   kernelspec in /usr/local/share/jupyter/kernels/apache_toree_scala
>   [ToreeInstall] Installed kernelspec apache_toree_scala in
>   /usr/local/share/jupyter/kernels/apache_toree_scala

and i though that everthing was successful but everytime i create an apache toree notebook i see the following:

[image]

It says Kernel busy and all of my commands are ignored..

I couldn't find anything about this issue online.
Alternatives to toree would also be accepted.

Thank you

Comment: have you check [Apache Zeppelin](https://zeppelin.apache.org/) out?

Answer (score 3):

Toree unfortunately does not work with Scala 2.11. Either you can downgrade to scala 2.10 with spark or use more recent version of toree(still in beta). The way I made it work with **spark 2.1 and Scala 2.11**:

```
#!/bin/bash
pip install -i https://pypi.anaconda.org/hyoon/simple toree
jupyter toree install --spark_home=$SPARK_HOME --user #will install scala + spark kernel
jupyter toree install --spark_home=$SPARK_HOME --interpreters=PySpark --user
jupyter kernelspec list
jupyter notebook #launch jupyter notebook
```

Look at this [post](https://medium.com/@muppal/aws-emr-jupyter-spark-2-x-7da54dc4bfc8) and this [post](https://www.3blades.io/blog/jupyter-notebook-apache-spark/) for more info.

It will eventually look like this:
[image]

Comment: Can confirm that this works for Spark 2.1.0 (Pyspark) and Scala 2.11.8, running on Linux Mint 18. Thanks!